# error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value in c on VS2008

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors

Hi  I was unable to find the cause of the compilation error while trying this code on Visual studio 2008.  I was trying to see an example of char* return value by a function .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
static char* getActiveModuleType(void);
void main()
{
char getActiveModuleBuff[128];
//error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
getActiveModuleBuff = getActiveModuleType();
printf("Active module in well formatted (2): %s\n",getActiveModuleBuff);

    exit(0);
 }
 char* getActiveModuleType(void)
 {
char activeModule[128];
int tempBuffLen=0;
int nbActivemodule = 0;
char moduleA        = 1;
char moduleB        = 1;
char moduleC        = 0;
char moduleD        = 1;
int i = 0;
if(moduleA==1) {activeModule[i] ='A'; activeModule[i+1]=','; i= i+2;}
if(moduleB==1) {activeModule[i] ='B'; activeModule[i+1]=','; i= i+2;}
if(moduleC==1) {activeModule[i] ='C'; activeModule[i+1]=','; i= i+2;}
if(moduleD==1) {activeModule[i] ='D'; activeModule[i+1]=','; i= i+2;}

printf(" Active module in : %s\n",activeModule);
//let get get the last ',' value trucated
tempBuffLen = strlen(activeModule);
nbActivemodule = tempBuffLen/2;
if((tempBuffLen == 0) && (nbActivemodule ==0)){
        memcpy(activeModule,"NoActiveModule",14);
        return activeModule;
}
if(activeModule[tempBuffLen-1]==',')
    activeModule[tempBuffLen-1] = '\0';
printf(" Active module in well formatted : %s\n",activeModule);

return activeModule;
}
```

i am unable to find why this Error C2106 occurs in this code .
Help required.
thanks

Comment: What it is trying to tell you is that left operand of `=` must be a *modifiable* lvalue. Arrays are lvalues, but as a whole they are not *modifiable*. You cannot assign anything to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char getActiveModuleBuff[128];
getActiveModuleBuff = getActiveModuleType();
```

You cannot assign a value to an array in C.

Use `memcpy` to copy an array or `strcpy` / `strncpy` to copy a string.

Also in:

```
 char* getActiveModuleType(void)
 {
     char activeModule[128];
     /* ... */
     return activeModule;
 }
```

the `activeModule` array object is destroyed at the end of the function. Accessing it after the function returns is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to what ouah said.

Don't return arrays. Instead, make your function write to an array passed to it as an argument, and return result code instead.

Change prototype of `getActiveModuleType` function to `void getActiveModuleType(char *activeModule)`. This will make the function take your array as a parameter and return nothing.

Then, delete the declaraction of `activeModule` from `getActiveModuleType`, because it's already declared as a parameter.

After `memcpy(activeModule,"NoActiveModule",14);`, replace `return activeModule;` with `return;`, because your function returns nothing (void). This will make your function exit on failure.

In the end of `getActiveModuleType`, delete `return activeModule;` line, because the function returns nothing.

And, in your `main` function, replace `getActiveModuleBuff = getActiveModuleType();` with `getActiveModuleType(getActiveModuleBuff);`.

Comment: Hi, 
I was trying a sample application to practice a function which return char* .
If i change the prototype of the function to return void, it won't solve the purpose of this sample code.

Comment: Trash the textbook where you saw that. Never return arrays. Never.